# Android logical operation &&?

Tags: java, android

This one has been giving me fits for over an hour... I could swear the code is right. Am I missing something?

```
if((fType != "EXACT") && (dateTime > System.currentTimeMillis())){ 
    myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyScheduledReceiver1.class);                        
} else {
    myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyScheduledReceiver2.class);
}
```

Even if the `String` `fType` is "EXACT" & `long` `dateTime` is in the future... it's still calling MyScheduledReceiver1.class... when since 1 is false it should be calling MyScheduledReceiver2.class.

Comment: Are you sure using operator> is available in java?

Comment: Something tells me you usually write in C#. ;)

Comment: @tstenner I'm pretty sure "greater than" is available in Java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is probably that you're comparing string *references* rather than comparing the values *within* the strings:

```
if (!fType.equals("EXACT") && dateTime > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    ...
}
```

That will now call the `equals` method on the string, which will compare whether the two character sequences are equal, rather than just whether `fType` and `"EXACT"` refer to the exact same `String` object.

(That will throw an exception if `fType` is null; if you want it to just not match you could use `if (!"EXACT".equals(fType) && ...)` - it depends on the situations.)

Comment: Thx... doing PHP and JAVA in the same doesn't sometimes isn't wise ;)

Comment: This is certainly it.  It's the first thing that jumps out at me.